# how to possible total cache plugin for only multi rating plugins?

Tags: wordpress

> When i use Total Cache plug-in multi rating does not update result without admin login so please give solution for it. in use of total cache plugin it will not updated value disply in front side for this plugins

Answer (score 0):

I see several ways to resolve your issue:
1. Go to the plugin Settings and change cache lifetime to 3600 seconds
2. Use another similar plugin (WP Super Cache, W3 Total Cache, WP Optimizer)